# Use of Matlab to put equation into vector form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matlab, computational-mathematics

Is there a way to put the following equation of a line into vector form using Matlab?

$\displaystyle y=\frac{cos(s_n)-cos(s_{n+1})}{sin(s_{n+1}-sin(s_n)}(x-sin(s_n))-cos(s_n)$

Comment: I suggest trying here as well: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/